# Generate "footprint" of songs (slow, fast, etc)

Tags: music, mp3

Over the years I have acquired a fairly large music collection of various genres and types of music.
Most of them are mp3s tagged with varying quality of tags. Not all and not all of them correctly and even if they would be, different songs of the same artist might be totally "different" (and different is a very fuzzy word)

If you are an US citizen, you probably might know pandora.com, sadly I think about 10 years ago it became unavailable in my country.

I am looking for something similar to pandora for my offline music. 
I know one can apply various analysis types to songs and obtain some metrics like bpm, loudness etc but I am curious whether there is a software (free or not) that is capable of generating those metrics and allow me to have playlists of based on those metrics.

For instance "quiet music", "slow music", "aggressive music" (good luck defining that :) ).

I am not looking for a software that fixes mp3 tags or pulls them from a music database but rather one that generates a footprint out of a song itself.

A Windows solution would be preferred. Linux would be ok too, but I would than have to export playlists somehow.

As mentioned, paid, free or open source is ok. Pricing for paid option is quite flexible. Highly depends on the feature set of course. Max $ 100 but probably rather less than $ 50.